# Выделяется ли "по возможности" запятыми с двух сторон?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, вводные-слова

Является ли **по возможности** вводным словом в данном варианте и выделяется ли с двух сторон запятыми?

*Я хочу проследить за Леонидом и(,) по возможности(,) узнать, к кому он ходит*;

*Нужно купить новый смартфон и(,) по возможности(,) отыскать для него чехол*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Наречное вырадение *по возможности* не требует запятых:

*Я хочу проследить за Леонидом и **по возможности** узнать, к кому он ходит*;

*Нужно купить новый смартфон и **по возможности** отыскать для него чехол*.

Но возможны и варианты с запятыми ([1-й пункт](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=114)), где автор хочет подчеркнуть **значимость этой фразы**:

*Я хочу проследить за Леонидом и, **по возможности**, узнать, к кому он ходит*;

*Нужно купить новый смартфон и, **по возможности**, отыскать для него чехол*.

Answer (score 1):

*Я хочу проследить за Леонидом и, **по возможности**, узнать, к кому он ходит.*

*Нужно купить новый смартфон и, **по возможности**, отыскать для него чехол.*

**Пояснение**

(1) Современный толковый словарь русского языка **Ефремовой:**

**По Возможности**,

1. **нареч. качеств.-обстоят.** Насколько возможно, по мере сил.
2. Употребляется как несогласованное определение.

(2) В общем случае обособление **[факультативное](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=114#pp114),** поэтому нужно сделать выбор.  Этот наречный оборот находится перед вторым однородным сказуемым после союза И, и **в этой позиции** его желательно обособить.